# How do I restrict access to one action of a controller using a token in the URL - Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I setup my controller to allow exceptions in the filter for a specific token in the URL.

For all intents and purposes of this demo the token is the character 'a'.

But now, when I go to the URL for that action, e.g. stage/7/compare and am not logged in, I can see it....how do I set i up so that if the token param isn't in the URL, it sends the user to login, but if it is allows them to see it without logging in (e.g. `stages/7/compare?token=a`) ?

This is what my Stages Controller looks like:

```
    class StagesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :check_token, :only => [:show]
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:compare]
    filter_access_to :all

  def show
    @stage = Stage.find(params[:id])
    render :layout => 'comparison'
    title = @stage.name
    #@upload = Upload.find(params[:id])

    #     respond_to do |format|
    #       format.html # show.html.erb
    #       format.xml  { render :xml => @stage }
    #     end
  end

  def compare
     @stage = Stage.find(params[:id])
      title = @stage.name
  end

    private

    def check_token
        stage = Stage.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(params[:token] == "a" ? compare_stage_path(stage) : root_path)      
    end

end
```

Edit1: 
If I change the `:check_token to :only [:compare]` this is what my log does:

```
Started GET "/stages/7/compare" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-30 18:45:05 -0500
  Processing by StagesController#compare as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
#<User id: 1, email: "test@abc.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$qUbNGm6lZ366jRiE0vK0gOpxbGXD5JmfqWmH1lfLlCEC...", password_salt: "$2a$10$qUbNGm6lZ366jRiE0vK0gO", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 251, current_sign_in_at: "2011-03-30 23:28:18", last_sign_in_at: "2011-03-30 21:57:13", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", username: "test", f_name: "Test", l_name: "User", created_at: "2011-01-22 07:17:45", updated_at: "2011-03-30 23:28:18", invitation_token: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, plan_id: 3, current_state: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2011-02-11 23:19:15", confirmation_sent_at: "2011-02-11 23:18:20">
  Stage Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "stages".* FROM "stages" WHERE ("stages"."id" = 7) LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 190ms
```

i.e. it redirects to my root_path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fixes the issue:

```
class StagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_token_or_user, :only => :compare
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show

  def show
    @stage = Stage.find(params[:id])
    render :layout => 'comparison'
  end

  def compare
    @stage = Stage.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def check_token_or_user
    if !user_signed_in && params[:token].blank?
      redirect_or_someting
    elsif !user.signed_in && params[:token].present? && params[:token] == "a"
      # do nothing, they can view the page
    elsif user_signed_in?
      # do nothing, they can view the page
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question asks about your `compare` action, but your `before_filter` is set to only operate on the `show` action.

```
before_filter :check_token, :only => [:compare]
```

Comment: I had that initially...the problem is that when I have it performs an endless redirect loop back to home. I have updated question with the loop from the logs.

Comment: Your logs don't indicate an endless loop. It looks like the app is doing precisely what you told it to do when there is no token param.

Comment: Right...here is the issue though...I was logged in. So when I am logged in, that shouldn't happen.

Comment: If you would like some free points, you can add the code I have added as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from voting this up (or down), but for the correct answer mark just wait the two days and mark yours.

Comment: Although this was not right, I voted you up for trying. Given that it seems you don't want the points, I will mark mine.